# Application tag in ASN.1 Declaration

Tags: snmp, asn.1, mib

Declaration IpAddress using Abstract Syntax Notation:

```
IpAddress ::= [APPLICATION 1] INTEGER (0..4294967295)
```

What does [APPLICATION 1] means in this code?!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note: This question is tagged SNMP, but this is not the proper declaration for SNMP's IpAddress type. This is actually a Counter32 type:

IpAddress ::=
    [APPLICATION 0]
        IMPLICIT OCTET STRING (SIZE (4))

Counter32 ::=
    [APPLICATION 1]
        IMPLICIT INTEGER (0..4294967295)

[RFC 2578](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2578.txt)

However;

An ASN.1 type has both a notation and an on-the-wire encoding. New types can be defined based on built-in types. In your question, a new type "IpAddress" is being defined as a finite-ranged (0..4294967295) derivation of the built-in "INTEGER" type, which has no built-in range restriction.

An ASN.1 encoding consists of three parts: a one-byte tag indicating the data type, a length for the content, and the content (value) itself. Without the part in [brackets], the encoding of the new type would be identical to the base type--in this case INTEGER, which has a tag value of 0x02 (hex). [APPLICATION 1] indicates that the value is to be encoded with a different tag so that you can distinguish its encoding from an INTEGER.

This part in [brackets] consists of an Tag Class and a Number. The Class can be UNIVERSAL (only used for built-in ASN.1 types), APPLICATION (which means application specific, i.e. [APPLICATION 1] to SNMP may mean something entirely different to [APPLICATION 1] in another protocol), PRIVATE for enterprise-specific, or may be omitted (in which case it is context-specific).

The Tag Class and Number are essentially bit flags that are or'ed together to form the tag value in the encoding. APPLICATION = 0x40, so [APPLICATION 1] means the value defined as in your question is encoded with a tag byte of 0x41.

However, as I mentioned above, this would actually be taken by SNMP to be a Counter32 value, not an IpAddress. 0x40 would be an IpAddress, and the contents would be encoded as an OCTET STRING rather than an INTEGER.

Answer (score 1):

It simply means "application-wide". Such types are not available in ASN.1, but available in SNMP (an application of ASN.1).

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1155

Section 3.2.3 gives more information on this.

The value behind `APPLICATION` is finally used in data encoding, to distinguish the types from each other.

You actually type something wrong, as `IpAddress` should use value 0, not 1.